# JpList Lightbox Not Working

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter, lightbox

I've added the JPList jQuery sort and filter plugin on our site.  The site gives examples on how to integrate Shadowbox.  However, Shadowbox has not worked well with our embeded Vimeo videos so we wanted to switch to Orangebox which is very similar and works well with Vimeo.

So, we've switched them out and referenced Orangebox but now the sort and filter doesn't work.  Here is a link to our site:  http://www.metrolibrary.org/stories/stories.htm

Here is the link to the demo:  http://do-web.com/jplist/demo-shadowbox

Can anyone help me figure this out?  I'm at a loss.